# Jackson XML - Can't deserialize Boolean

Tags: java, spring, jackson-dataformat-xml

I'm trying to parse XML content with Jackson but I have some difficulties with Boolean value.
This is a part of my XML content :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soap:Body xmlns:ns1="http://somecontent">
    <wsResponse xmlns="http://somecontent">
      <responseType>SUCCESS</responseType>
      <response>
        <successfullResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="InterchangeSearchResponse">
          <totalResult>1</totalResult>
          <returnedResults>1</returnedResults>
          <pageIndex>1</pageIndex>
          <interchanges>
            <interchange>
              <depositId>somecontent</depositId>
              <interchangeId>somecontent</interchangeId>
              <depositDate>2021-03-26T11:45:05.000+01:00</depositDate>
              <depositSubject>dépôt WS</depositSubject>
              <numADS>number</numADS>
              <adsDate>2021-03-26T11:45:05.000+01:00</adsDate>
              <alias>contentAsString</alias>
              <version xsi:nil="true"/>
              <isTest>false</isTest>
              <deposantAccount>
                <name>someString</name>
              </deposantAccount>
              <teleProcedure>someString</teleProcedure>
              <statesHistory>
```

This is my XML structure as class :

```
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Body")
    private Body body;

    public Body getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(Body body) {
        this.body = body;
    }
}
```

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement
public class Body {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Fault")
    private Fault fault;
    private WsResponse wsResponse;

    public Fault getFault() {
        return fault;
    }
    public void setFault(Fault fault) {
        this.fault = fault;
    }
    public WsResponse getWsResponse() {
        return wsResponse;
    }
    public void setWsResponse(WsResponse wsResponse) {
        this.wsResponse = wsResponse;
    }
}
```

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "wsResponse")
public class WsResponse {
    private String responseType;
    private Response response;

    public String getResponseType() {
        return responseType;
    }
    public void setResponseType(String responseType) {
        this.responseType = responseType;
    }

    public Response getResponse() {
        return response;
    }
    public void setResponse(Response response) {
        this.response = response;
    }
}
```

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement
public class Response {
    private SuccessfulResponse successfullResponse;
    private ErrorResponse errorResponse;

    public SuccessfulResponse getSuccessfullResponse() {
        return successfullResponse;
    }
    public void setSuccessfullResponse(SuccessfulResponse successfullResponse) {
        this.successfullResponse = successfullResponse;
    }

    public ErrorResponse getErrorResponse() {
        return errorResponse;
    }
    public void setErrorResponse(ErrorResponse errorResponse) {
        this.errorResponse = errorResponse;
    }
}
```

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement
public class SuccessfulResponse {
    /**
     * Response when add document success
     */
    private String depositId;

    /**
     * Response when get interchanges by deposit id success
     */
    private String type;
    private Integer totalResult;
    private Integer returnedResults;
    private Integer pageIndex;
    private Interchanges interchanges;

    /**
     * Response when get declaration details success
     */
    private DeclarationTdfc declarationTdfc;

    public SuccessfulResponse() {}

    public SuccessfulResponse(String depositId) {
        this.depositId = depositId;
    }

    public SuccessfulResponse(String type, Integer totalResult, Integer returnedResults, Integer pageIndex, Interchanges interchanges) {
        this.type = type;
        this.totalResult = totalResult;
        this.returnedResults = returnedResults;
        this.pageIndex = pageIndex;
        this.interchanges = interchanges;
    }

    public SuccessfulResponse(DeclarationTdfc declarationTdfc) {
        this.declarationTdfc = declarationTdfc;
    }

    public SuccessfulResponse(String depositId, String type, Integer totalResult, Integer returnedResults,
                              Integer pageIndex, Interchanges interchanges, DeclarationTdfc declarationTdfc) {
        super();
        this.depositId = depositId;
        this.type = type;
        this.totalResult = totalResult;
        this.returnedResults = returnedResults;
        this.pageIndex = pageIndex;
        this.interchanges = interchanges;
        this.declarationTdfc = declarationTdfc;
    }

    public String getDepositId() {
        return depositId;
    }
    public void setDepositId(String depositId) {
        this.depositId = depositId;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public Integer getTotalResult() {
        return totalResult;
    }
    public void setTotalResult(Integer totalResult) {
        this.totalResult = totalResult;
    }
    public Integer getReturnedResults() {
        return returnedResults;
    }
    public void setReturnedResults(Integer returnedResults) {
        this.returnedResults = returnedResults;
    }
    public Integer getPageIndex() {
        return pageIndex;
    }
    public void setPageIndex(Integer pageIndex) {
        this.pageIndex = pageIndex;
    }
    public Interchanges getInterchanges() {
        return interchanges;
    }
    public void setInterchanges(Interchanges interchanges) {
        this.interchanges = interchanges;
    }

    public DeclarationTdfc getDeclarationTdfc() {
        return declarationTdfc;
    }

    public void setDeclarationTdfc(DeclarationTdfc declarationTdfc) {
        this.declarationTdfc = declarationTdfc;
    }
}
```

```
public class Interchanges {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "interchange")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private List<Interchange> interchange;

    public Interchanges() { super(); }

    public Interchanges(List<Interchange> interchange) {
        super();
        this.interchange = interchange;
    }

    public List<Interchange> getInterchange() {
        return interchange;
    }

    public void setInterchange(List<Interchange> interchange) {
        this.interchange = interchange;
    }
}
```

```
public class Interchange {
    private String depositId;
    private Integer interchangeId;
    //@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = SelfmedConstants.Dates.ENGLISH_DATETIME_PATTERN)
    private String depositDate;
    private String depositSubject;
    private String numADS;
    //@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = SelfmedConstants.Dates.ENGLISH_DATETIME_PATTERN)
    private String adsDate;
    private String alias;
    //@JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String version;
    @JsonSerialize(using = BooleanSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = BooleanDeserializer.class)
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "isTest")
    private Boolean isTest;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "name")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "deposantAccount")
    private List<String> name;
    private String teleProcedure;
    private StatesHistory statesHistory;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "declarationId")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "declarationIds")
    private List<String> declarationId;

    public Interchange() {
    }

    public Interchange(String depositId, Integer interchangeId, String depositDate, String depositSubject, String numADS,
                       String adsDate, String alias, String version, Boolean isTest, List<String> name, String teleProcedure,
                       StatesHistory statesHistory, List<String> declarationId) {
        this();
        this.depositId = depositId;
        this.interchangeId = interchangeId;
        this.depositDate = depositDate;
        this.depositSubject = depositSubject;
        this.numADS = numADS;
        this.adsDate = adsDate;
        this.alias = alias;
        this.version = version;
        this.isTest = isTest;
        this.name = name;
        this.teleProcedure = teleProcedure;
        this.statesHistory = statesHistory;
        this.declarationId = declarationId;
    }

    public String getDepositId() {
        return depositId;
    }
    public void setDepositId(String depositId) {
        this.depositId = depositId;
    }

    public Integer getInterchangeId() {
        return interchangeId;
    }

    public void setInterchangeId(Integer interchangeId) {
        this.interchangeId = interchangeId;
    }

    public String getDepositDate() {
        return depositDate;
    }

    public void setDepositDate(String depositDate) {
        this.depositDate = depositDate;
    }

    public String getDepositSubject() {
        return depositSubject;
    }

    public void setDepositSubject(String depositSubject) {
        this.depositSubject = depositSubject;
    }

    public String getNumADS() {
        return numADS;
    }

    public void setNumADS(String numADS) {
        this.numADS = numADS;
    }

    public String getAdsDate() {
        return adsDate;
    }

    public void setAdsDate(String adsDate) {
        this.adsDate = adsDate;
    }

    public String getAlias() {
        return alias;
    }

    public void setAlias(String alias) {
        this.alias = alias;
    }

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public Boolean getIsTest() {
        return isTest;
    }

    public void setIsTest(Boolean isTest) {
        this.isTest = isTest;
    }

    public void setIsTest(String isTest) {
        this.isTest = Boolean.valueOf(isTest);
    }

    public List<String> getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(List<String> name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getTeleProcedure() {
        return teleProcedure;
    }

    public void setTeleProcedure(String teleProcedure) {
        this.teleProcedure = teleProcedure;
    }

    public StatesHistory getStatesHistory() {
        return statesHistory;
    }

    public void setStatesHistory(StatesHistory statesHistory) {
        this.statesHistory = statesHistory;
    }

    public List<String> getDeclarationId() {
        return declarationId;
    }

    public void setDeclarationId(List<String> declarationId) {
        this.declarationId = declarationId;
    }
}
```

As you can see in the Interchange class, I try some stuff but nothing work.

I generate my class like that :

```
JacksonXmlModule xmlModule = new JacksonXmlModule();
            xmlModule.setDefaultUseWrapper(false);

            XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper(xmlModule);
            xmlMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT, true);
            xmlMapper.enable(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_VALUES);
            System.out.println(responseAsString);
            Envelope envelope = xmlMapper.readValue(responseAsString, new TypeReference<>() {
```

But when I try to parse my content, I got this exception :

> Cannot construct instance of `payload.response.Interchange` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('false')
> at [Source: (StringReader); line: 20, column: 28] (through reference chain: payload.response.Envelope["Body"]->payload.response.Body["wsResponse"]->payload.response.WsResponse["response"]->payload.response.Response["successfullResponse"]->payload.response.SuccessfulResponse["interchanges"]->payload.response.Interchanges["interchange"]->java.util.ArrayList[1])

I try a lot of things but nothing work so I'm wondering if the problem may be not here...
If you have any solution or leads to explore, please let me know !

Thank.

Answer (score 0):

According to JavaBean spec you have to name getter `isTest()`.

Comment: Hi, thank for the answer. Unfortunately even if I rename the getter to ```isTest()```, it doesn't change the result. I got the same exception.